# Set device owner adb launcher android ERROR: Bad admin

Tags: android, adb, launcher, kiosk-mode

I'm tring to create a launcher (kiosk-mode) which is the device owner, some days ago, I had execute this command with a positive result, but now, I don't now why adb is returning the next result, I use adb to execute the next command to do it:

Command: `adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.x.launcher/.AdminReceiver`

Result: `Error: Bad admin: ComponentInfo{com.x.launcher/com.x.launcher.AdminReceiver}`

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher"
        tools:targetApi="29">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Device Administration Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".AdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin"/>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AdminReceiver.java

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.device_admin_enabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return context.getString(R.string.device_admin_warning);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.device_admin_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLockTaskModeEntering(Context context, Intent intent, String pkg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.kiosk_mode_enabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLockTaskModeExiting(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.kiosk_mode_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

device_admin.xml

```
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

I think that the error is related with nomenclature.